# Can not get QT Bluetooth module to work with Virtual Box Ubuntu

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, bluetooth, virtualbox

I have created a small program using QT creator 4.14.0 (QT 5.15.2), using c++ and QML. I am creating, building and running the program on Ubuntu using Virtual box on a windows 10 system. I have installed bluez and other bluetooth packages on the virtual Ubuntu system as per instructions I've found online, and I have bluetooth working in the Ubuntu operating system, I can scan for devices using the Bluetooth quick-tray item and it finds what it's supposed to find, the bluetooth adapter works.

However, when I run my program I get the the following under Application output **"qt.bluetooth: Dummy backend running. Qt Bluetooth module is non-functional."**, and the bluetooth scan never starts (no further output). From what I can gather by research it seems like QT thinks that the system can not support Bluetooth, and uses a "dummy stub" in lieu of the actual working code. I have researched what I can about how to resolve this, but I can not find anything I can apply to my own code/setup. I would be appreciative of any help I can get.

Here's the relevant code:

```
// this is bluetooth_scanner.h
#ifndef BLUETOOTH_SCANNER_H
#define BLUETOOTH_SCANNER_H

#include <QObject> 
#include <QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent>
#include <QBluetoothDeviceInfo>
#include <QDir>
#include <QTextStream>

class bluetooth_scanner : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT 

public:
    bluetooth_scanner();
    void startDeviceDiscovery();

public slots:
    void deviceDiscovered(const QBluetoothDeviceInfo &device);

};

#endif // BLUETOOTH_SCANNER_H
```

```
// this is bluetooth_scanner.cpp
#include "bluetooth_scanner.h"


// constructor
bluetooth_scanner::bluetooth_scanner()
{

}

void bluetooth_scanner::startDeviceDiscovery()
{

    // Create a discovery agent and connect to its signals
    QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent *discoveryAgent = new QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent(); // was 'this' inside parantheses, got build error, removed == no build error

    QObject::connect(discoveryAgent, SIGNAL(deviceDiscovered(QBluetoothDeviceInfo)),this,  SLOT(deviceDiscovered(QBluetoothDeviceInfo)));

    // Start a discovery
    discoveryAgent->start();

}

// In your local slot, read information about the found devices
void bluetooth_scanner::deviceDiscovered(const QBluetoothDeviceInfo &device)
{
    // init QT printing
    QTextStream out(stdout);

    out << "Found new device:" << device.name() << '(' << device.address().toString() << ')' << endl;
}
```

```
// this is main.cpp
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <bluetooth_scanner.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    // test bluetooth C++ scan function
    bluetooth_scanner *bt_scan = new bluetooth_scanner();
    bt_scan->startDeviceDiscovery();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Please do supply `main` and any other code needed to build the project so that others can test and debug it (Makefile or an equivalent is helpful too)

Comment: I've added main.cpp, the makefile is very long, should I really paste the whole thing?